# How to change the default 'fill-in' color in Excel for Mac?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

When you're in Excel, you can fill a cell with a color (the icon is the paint bucket with yellow paint spilling out). I want to change that so the default color is green, not yellow as it always is.  Every time I open that Excel sheet, I want that paint bucket to always be green by default.

How do I do that in Excel for Mac?

Comment: what do you mean by "fill-in" color?

Comment: When you're in excel and you can fill in a cell with a color (the icon is the paint bucket with yellow paint spilling out). I want to change that so the default color on there is green NOT yellow as it always is. So everytime I would open that excel sheet, that yellow buck will always be green.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Open a blank workbook and change the fill color to the green you want.

Then "Save As" and name the file "Workbook".
Navigate to 
`Applications/Microsoft Office 2011(or your version)/Office/Startup/Excel` 
and click Save.

Then open your finder and navigate to the folder you saved the Workbook file in. Find the file, "right" click and select "Get Info", and delete the ".xltx" file extension from the name of the file. Click OK (it might say "Remove") on the warning message.

In theory, this should replace the "blank" workbook that opens when you open Excel. I haven't personally tried this, so your mileage may vary. I also don't know if you'd need to "Save As" every time you save a new file.